# How to set Background of a TextView dynamically from Xml file

Tags: android, textview, xml-drawable

I have an xml file like below which I will use to set background for `Textview`:

## row.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient android:endColor="#CCCCCC" android:startColor="#CCCCCC"
      android:angle="270" />
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#999999" />
      <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp" /></shape>
```

The above Xml I will set as background for TextView in main.xml as below:

## main.xml

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/rowtext3"
android:text="Availablity"
android:layout_height="25px"
android:layout_width="60px"
android:textSize="10px"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/row"
/>
```

But I want this to do from code rather than Xml.I have done everything  that I have done in Xml like font, width, Height, font dynamically through code, but not able to set Background that I mentioned in Xml file. How can we set content of Xml file as background to textview similar to how we set background as XML in main.xml.

In the code I have done like this:

```
    t1=new TextView(this); <br>
    t1.setText(ed1.getText()); <br>
    t1.setHeight(25); <br>
    t1.setWidth(60); <br>
    t1.setTextSize(10); <br>
```

But I didn't find how to set background i.e. how to set XML content as background? 
Can any one help me in sorting out this issue? 
Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the method you're looking for is `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)`.

This will set the background using the given Drawable. So it would look something like this:

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowtext3);
t1.setBackgroundDrawable(row);
```

Comment: I tried the way u suggested as below:                       TextView tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ttt);
tt.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.row); I am getting error as "The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)". How can I resolve this issue? But I am creating textview also dynamically in the activity file,there is no need for me to get reference from XML file.

Comment: That's because `setBackgroundDrawable()` does not accept an int as an argument. Try using the same technique but with the method `setBackgroundResource()` which accepts an int resource (Drawable object) ID.

Comment: Hi,Can u give me sample code for how to create a RelativeLayout dynamically through code with 2 textviews one below other.I want to implement android:layout_below feature through code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, [`findViewById(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) from the Activity class is what you're looking for. When you have retrieved the view, you can set the background using `setBackgroundResource(int id)`. The parameter *id* can be found in your generated R-file, e.g. `findViewById(R.drawable.row)`.

Comment: t1.setBackgroundResource(findViewById(R.drawable.row));

Comment: Hi, I give like you suggested in my activity :t1.setBackgroundResource(findViewById(R.drawable.row)); It was showing error as "The method setBackgroundResource(int ) in the type view is not applicable for the arguments view. " How can I resolve this error in order to setBackground for TextView .