# DalvikError with my Function

Tags: android, dalvik

I wrote a function to set the background of a view depending on the android version:

```
package com.pthuermer.juraquiz;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;

public class SupportFunctions {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(View v, Drawable drawable) {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
    else {
        v.setBackground(drawable);
    }
}

}
```

This is how I call it:

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_app_background);
SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(fl, drawable);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_app_launch);
Drawable drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_heading_background);
SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(tv, drw);
```

It works for `fl`but not for `tv` it breaks down with these errors:

```
Pick [Android Application]
```

Pick [Android Application]
Pick [Android Application]
Pick [Android Application]
Pick [Android Application]
    DalvikVM [localhost:8600] 
Pick [Android Application]
    DalvikVM [localhost:8600]
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
            
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2295
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2349 
            ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 159
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1316
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Looper.loop() line: 137 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5419
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1187 
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1003
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)

Comment: Let it continue, and check the full log message you get in `logcat`.  The exception message may have useful detail.

Comment: `sendUserActionEvent() mView == null` says the log cat

Comment: In the stacktrace, I can *NOT* found a full error stack. Please post more exception log here. And there is a question for TextView setBackground: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901813/how-to-set-background-of-a-textview-dynamically-from-xml-file