# Function call results in Dalvik error

Tags: android, json, http

In my activity I'm calling a function:

```
JSONObject jObj = SupportFunctions.returnJSONObject(url);
```

The function looks like this:

```
public static JSONObject returnJSONObject(String url) {

    JSONObject jObj = null;
    InputStream iS = null;
    String result = null;

    // HTTP
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        iS = entity.getContent();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("QUIZ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

The call results in:

```
Pick [Android Application] <terminated>Pick [Android Application]   
<disconnected>DalvikVM [localhost:8600] 
    Pick [Android Application]  
DalvikVM [localhost:8600] (may be out of synch) 
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2295    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2349 
        ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 159    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1316  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5419    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1187 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1003    
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<11> Binder_3] (Running) (may be out of synch)  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running) (may be out of synch)  
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) (may be out of synch)
```

Why does the call produce this error? `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);` seems to be the line that fails!

Comment: post your `LogCat` error.

Comment: there is no logcat-error

Comment: you are returning `jObj` wuthout assigning any value, it's `null`, it makes no sense

Comment: well, I cut out the part that gives value to jObj because its not the reason for the error

Comment: what is on line: 2295

Comment: an `else statement` in my `ActivityThread.java`

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489054/dalvikerror-with-my-function, it's easier to figure out if you let the app crash and pull the exception out of logcat than it is to sort through the debugger stack.  The full trace includes the various "caused by" parts, shows the exception message, and you may find some useful messages just above the exception in the log file.  Also, this is not a "Dalvik error", it's a `RuntimeException` apparently thrown by the framework.

Comment: so? what shall I do. I didn't let it fail on purpose.

Comment: `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);` 
seems to be the line that fails!

Comment: This seems to be a thread dump from DDMS. I can see your activity is suspended. Did you call android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger() ?

Comment: where do I have to call this?

Comment: You must not use network resources from main thread. Create an async task or start a new thread to do those http requests.

Comment: is that the reason for the program to fail or just something I should consider?

Comment: By design, Android apps will crash in any http request in main thread.  You should be able to see the exactly exception in logcat.

Comment: there is no log cat error. okay so I need to extend my class by AsyncTask, right?

Comment: @Philip - run it for real, not under the debugger (and make sure you have no catch blocks which silently swallow errors), let it fail, and *then* get the full stacktrace from logcat all the way to the "caused by".  However it seems like the cause has already been pointed out, and the network on main thread issue has many duplicate questions here.

Comment: If you do a http request, it must throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException. If you can see, probably your dev tools is not working fine, you did catch the exception or some thing else. And yes, you can extend AsyncTask

Comment: can you help me out a little. I'm not quite sure how to get along with this

Comment: how can I change the return type of doInBackground to JSONObject? I don't know how I shall use this for my purposes..

Comment: works with asynctask. thanks!

Comment: Great! Seems like you got it working while I was being more specific in a answer :p

Comment: haha oh sorry :D but I got one more question :/
how do I get my JSONArray (I changed it from Object to Array) out of
`AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONArray> as = new LoadJSONFromURL().execute(url);` ?

Comment: My answer tells that. You can use a class field in your activity and then the async task assigns the json array to that field. In my sample, the field is defined as `JSONObject mJsonObj`. You can just change id to JSONArray type.

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong. Getting dalvik error again.
My Program doesn't know JsonParser

Comment: -1 What "dalvik error"?  As requested many comments ago, make sure you have no silent catch blocks, run *without* the debugger until crash, then post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think Philip is misunderstanding the concepts. When an application which is attached to the eclipse's built-in debug crashes, eclipe take focus to debug view and the app stops. He is wrongly calling this of dalvik error. Philip, when you got stock in this state, try press F8 and pay attention to logcat.

Comment: That's why I've said, for the third time now, that he should run *without* the debugger for purposes of easily capturing the stack trace.  The downvote is for not providing that critical information in the question; it can be removed when the actual stack trace of the error is edited into the question.

Answer (score 1):

From you question, I can see that the main thread is suspended. Assuming that you are performing a HTTP request in main thread, this may be you issue. Usually it trows a NetworkOnMainThreadException and I believe this is what will happen when you go ahead with the debugger.

As you must not do a HTTP request in  main thread, a solution can be:

```
JSONArray mJsonArray;

// Inner class to do http request out from main thread
class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
        InputStream iS = null;

        // HTTP
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            iS = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("QUIZ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        if (iS != null) {
            mJsonArray = new JSONArray(urlInputStream.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // A toast to inform that the http requeset just finished.
        // The json object will be available in mJsonArray class field.
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "HTTP request finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Finally, to create the async task and run it:

```
new HttpRequestTask().execute(url);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. my Program doesn't know JsonParser.

Comment: JsonParser is an hypotetical class which would read your input stream and create/parse it to a json object. I edited with a real method now.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the issue but we never know : did you ask for Internet permission in the manifest ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```